# Define range and clear its contents

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have this long report in which in few columns there are 0 values continued for many hundreds of rows. The 0 values usually begin around row 50 but sometimes can begin only at row 200.
I have a code which does what it was required to, but takes enormous resources of the PC and can take up to few hours to process thus holds the whole process.

```
Application.Goto Workbooks("doc_flow_report.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a2")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "B").Value = Cells(i, "G").Value Then
            Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I want to use another approach for it, might be faster for Excel to digest. The process steps would be:

1. Define a range starting with first row in column B where there is 0 value and going down to last row of column P with 0 value
2. Clear the contents of the range.

Thanks for any hints

Comment: Do you want to *clear the content* (and keep the empty rows - as written in your question) or do you want to *delete the rows* (as in your code)? Also: your code doesn't check for 0s but for equality with columng G ...

Comment: Using `Sort` and then you'll have all 0 values in continous Rows, making it easy to delete (Excels Sort function is really fast) - Also usually when working with Values of big Ranges, it is a good practice to put the values into an array and work with the array, and only at the end put the array back into the actual sheet. (Operations on Arrays are way faster than operations on Sheets)

Comment: I assume clearing the content might be faster than deleting rows (some of the rows for deletion have functions linked to other files). Also the report is sorted and the 0 values are in continuous rows until the last not empty row.

Comment: There are several ways to skin this cat:  Set up your data as a Table (List Object), filter the Table and then Delete the DataRange.  You could use Power Query to filter the data and then replace your original data with the queried data.  You could use a Filter function to filter out the data on a separate helper sheet, copy paste as values to a 2nd helper sheet and then replace your original data with that data.  Your first attempt is the slowest possible method of cleaning up data that can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Range.Find` twice:

```
Sub CincoDeMayo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Workbooks("doc_flow_report.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim startCell As Range
    Set startCell = ws.Range("B:B").Find( _
        What:=0, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    
    Dim endCell As Range
    Set endCell = ws.Range("P:P").Find( _
        What:=0, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    
    If Not startCell Is Nothing And Not endCell Is Nothing Then
        ws.Range(startCell, endCell).EntireRow.Delete
        ' or change .Delete to .ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that the first `Find` starts searching *after* cell `B1`. This shouldn't be a problem, based on your description: "The 0 values usually begin around row 50."

Comment: Is `SearchDirection` remembered? If so, you might want to specify it for both, in case this is run more than once?

Comment: @CLR only `LookIn`, `LookAt`, `SearchOrder`, and `MatchByte`, if the docs can be trusted. But I'll add it to be explicit, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

### Clear a Range

- You can use the more efficient (not so relevant here: only one match) `Application.Match` to determine the row index of a matching (found) value in a single column.

```vb
Sub RemoveTrailingZeros()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = Workbooks("doc_flow_report.xlsx")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The workbook is not open.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim rg As Range
    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' nice data: no empty rows or columns
    'With ws.UsedRange ' nothing but the relevant data is in the worksheet
        Set rg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' exclude headers
    End With
    
    Dim mrIndex: mrIndex = Application.Match(0, rg.Columns(2), 0)
    If IsError(mrIndex) Then
        MsgBox "No zeros found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Cells(mrIndex + 1, "A")
    Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = rg.Cells(rg.Cells.CountLarge)
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = ws.Range(fCell, lCell)
    
    crg.Clear
    
    MsgBox "Trailing zeros removed.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```